# ObjC: Can a large number of calls to a super method that does nothing ever cause slowness?

Tags: objective-c

For example, in the Cocoa Framework, most of the touches methods do nothing unless you implement them.  If, in all similar methods throughout my program, I call [super method:] before my custom implementation, would that ever cause realistic slowdown (hundredths of a second)?

Maybe a stupid question...But I ask since I don't know the low-level specifics of what a message costs.

Comment: sorry, duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907843/cost-of-message-dispatch-in-objective-c

Comment: @Johannes: I partly disagree. Calling `[super method:]` takes a different route than `[ordinary_object method:]`.

Comment: it's really marginal, isn't it?

Comment: Very marginal;  objc_msgSend and objc_msgSendSuper are pretty close to identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: Messages are incredibly fast in the Obj-C runtime. The compiler optimizes the calls, the runtime optimizes the dispatch. If you're calling messages in tight loops millions of times a frame to build graphics geometry, then you'd consider the impact. Otherwise, no, *especially* for stuff like calling super on user input, which by definition is orders of magnitude less frequent than the system's other bookkeeping.

Exercise for the interested: Profile your app with Shark and check it out for kicks. The message dispatcher is called something like `objc_msgSend`.