# In general is invoking and @selector slow?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

When creating an iOS program is there any performance hit if I pass around SELs (@selectors) and invoke them in other classes? Is this significantly slower than normal method invocations?

Comment: Great answers here for exactly this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907843/cost-of-message-dispatch-in-objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would there be a performance hit for messaging (the one thing ObjC is famous for) from other classes?  Of course, compared to C functions, there is some overhead (thanks to the addition of two more parts to a method).  Selectors are simply data types, so passing them to type SEL is no more costly than sending a BOOL or an int over.  However, to actually call a SEL type from a passed selector, the creation of an NSInvocation object is recommended, which would slightly increase the overhead time.

And you are more or less safe in objC, as messages to nil (you did mention other classes), produce nil.

Comment: So, is calling [obj performSelector:sel] slow?

Comment: Judge for yourself, [the speed test is here](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/performance-comparisons-of-common-operations.html)

Comment: @CodaFi I just took a look and didn't see any metrics for `performSelector:...` invocations on the page you linked. I would think there'd be some additional overhead because of the extra method invocation.

Comment: It technically doesn't matter, as all selectors boil down to objc_msg_send anyhow.  And you are right about the double method incursion.

Answer (score 0):

Well it might not have much of effect except on first run as compiler creates a reference to every objects and it's dependencies along with classes at compile time , so it might be a bit slow at loading time(that too in very large programs..) but not much after that provided not very big objects are created in the intermediate steps and also it doesn't involve any large dynamic operation as here i am talking only about calling a local function and calling the same function from a different class.

Anyways why would you use selector to reference to some function in a different class.

Answer (score 0):

From my limited knowledge, a selector is simply an encoding of a method name.  Given that in objective-c methods are called by sending messages to objects, I don't see why there should be a performance difference between an explicit method call (`[object method]`) and an implicit call (`[objectDelegate selector]`).