# Method Swizzling - Routing every method call through a custom logger without the need to change the underlying method

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, method-swizzling

I am trying to write a framework that would print certain log statements including class name and method name while that method is called on an object of that class. I want to do this without the need to modify the actual method. For instance, say there is a method `-(void)sendButtonClicked`, when control reaches this method the framework intercept and print the class and method name on console.

This is something like [Method Swizzling](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/).

Any clue?

Comment: It sounds like a job for aspect-oriented programming.  Maybe this will lead to clues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136535/does-swift-support-aspect-oriented-programming

Comment: Yes you are right @PhillipMills. Initial read of the shared link suggest what I am looking for. Thank you for sharing this!